# Find all the ancestors of leaf nodes in a tree with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tree

I have a table that has two columns, 'parent' and 'child'. This is a download from SAP (ERP) for SETNODE table. Need to create a dataframe in python that has each level as it's own column in respect to it's parent and all levels before.

In python 3+.

There are an unknown (or always changing) number of levels for the full relationship so that max level can't always be defined. I would like to create a full dataframe table that shows ALL parent/child relationships for all levels. Right now it's about 15 levels but it can probably go up to 20 or more with other data I work with.

For example (example_df) of the two columns:

[image]

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'parent:['a','a','b','c','c','f'],'child':['b','c','d','f','g','h']})
```

To give output dataframe (solution_example):

[image]

```
solution_example = pd.DataFrame({'child':['h','f','d'],'parent_1':['a','a','a'],'parent_2':['c','c','b'],'parent_3':['f', 'none', 'none']})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using the `networkx` library. First, build a directed graph from the DataFrame, and then find all ancestors of the leaf nodes.

```
import networkx as nx

leaves = set(df.child).difference(df.parent)
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
ancestors = {
    n: nx.algorithms.dag.ancestors(g, n) for n in leaves
}

(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ancestors, orient='index')
   .rename(lambda x: 'parent_{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)
   .rename_axis('child')
   .fillna(''))

      parent_1 parent_2 parent_3
child                           
h            a        c        f
g            a        c         
d            a        b
```

Comment: This works and is much appreciated. However, for my data there is one issue. When running code above, the "parent_1" isn't always in the parent_1 column. This creates an issue because I need to filter off the "parent_1" data to ensure my top level since I can't filter the child/parent data from the initial data. Is there a way to ensure the parent lables are all in the correct order?

Comment: @rgh_dsa you can use python3.6 where sets and dicts are ordered. In that case I believe the first column should represent the topmost ancestor.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this. I need to filter on a specific "parent" in my case named "ZF_ALLACCOUNTS". Since it's all out of order I can only do this: solution[solution.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('ZF_ALLACCOUNTS', case=False).any(), axis=1)]. But...for my needs I need the order correct for the parents. Can you point me in any other direction to help? Thank you!

Comment: @rgh_dsa I have an idea: you can [topologically sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html) your graph to get a list of sorted nodes, then you can order the parent nodes by the order in which they appear in the sorted list. Does this sound good?

Comment: Yes! I'll try it out and comment back if any other issues arise. Thanks again!

Comment: I can't get it to work and curious if there is any way you could add more about how to do what you suggested with the topologically sort?

Comment: @rgh_dsa It would not be appropriate to add information cursory to the question topic at hand, as that would make this question too broad. What I suggest is opening a followup question that asks how to get ancestors in topologically sorted order.